# Docusign Java Client SDK support for JDK 1.8

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Do we have a Docusign Java client SDK that's compatible with JDK 1.8? Has anyone tried using Docusign Java Client SDK with 1.8? The latest SDK version needs JDK 1.9+. Reference - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/tree/3.6.0 seems to be the last version that supports JDK 1.8.